# How do I fix these illegal string offset warnings?

Tags: php, wordpress

**Context:** On one of the sites where my WordPress plugin is installed I'm seeing a series of PHP warnings, but I'm not entirely sure why this is happening. I'm hoping someone here can help me figure out how to solve this warning.

**Code Sample:**

```
function my_function( $array ) {

   if ( ! isset( $array['where'] ) ) { $array['where'] = 'after'; }
   if ( ! isset( $array['echo'] ) ) { $array['echo'] = false; }
   if ( ! isset( $array['content'] ) ) { $array['content'] = false; }

   $array['shortcode'] = true;
   $array['devs'] = true;
   return social_warfare( $array );
}

add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_function' );
```

**The Warning:**

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'where' in
>   /home/playitda/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/functions/frontend-output/shortcodes.php
>   on line 14
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'echo' in
>   /home/playitda/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/functions/frontend-output/shortcodes.php
>   on line 15
>
> Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in
>   /home/playitda/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/functions/frontend-output/shortcodes.php
>   on line 15
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' in
>   /home/playitda/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/functions/frontend-output/shortcodes.php
>   on line 16
>
> Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in
>   /home/playitda/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/functions/frontend-output/shortcodes.php
>   on line 16
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'shortcode' in
>   /home/playitda/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/functions/frontend-output/shortcodes.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'devs' in
>   /home/playitda/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/functions/frontend-output/shortcodes.php
>   on line 19

For some reason, it's throwing a warning every time it encounters one of the indices in the array. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the function is expecting an array and is getting a string instead.

Comment: So how can I force that to be an array? Do I declare it in the parameters or perhaps check for it and make it an array before continuing?

Comment: Yes, you can ['type hint'](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) (well more than hint now with 7.+) in function signature or explicitly check for type... `is_array`. Fix though is not to pass a string when expecting an array.

Comment: I like that is_array check, because that way if some lughead passes a non-array into it, I can simply unset it and then use my default array values instead without it throwing an error.

Comment: `if ( ! is_array ( $array ) ) $array = [];` at the beginning of the function will insure you have an array

Comment: Should I unset the $array before redeclaring it as an array?  if(!is_array($array)){
  unset($array);
  $array = array();
 }

Comment: No need. PHP, in latest versions does have a garbage collector

Comment: Okay, perfect. Thanks. If you want to write  that up as in an answer form, I'll gladly select this for you as the chosen solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the function [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) in the beginning of your function can give you the insurance, that, if someone pass you something else than an array, the variable is reinitialised as an empty array.

Unsetting or nulling it before doing that is useless, because, as of PHP 5.3, PHP does have a [garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) mechanism.

```
/**
 * @params array $array
 */
function my_function( $array ) {
   if ( ! is_array ( $array ) ) { $array = [] };
   /**
    * Or, if you don't like the short array notation:
    * if ( ! is_array ( $array ) ) { $array = array(); };
    */

   if ( ! isset( $array['where'] ) ) { $array['where'] = 'after'; }
   if ( ! isset( $array['echo'] ) ) { $array['echo'] = false; }
   if ( ! isset( $array['content'] ) ) { $array['content'] = false; }

   $array['shortcode'] = true;
   $array['devs'] = true;
   return social_warfare( $array );
}

add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_function' );
```

Comment: While the other answer is certainly a good one, I'm choosing this one as the accepted solution because this one ensures that if some random user calling the function passes something improperly to it, then the function will catch it, reset the array and continue doing what it is designed to do. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the function is expecting an array and is getting a string instead.

You can require an array in the function definition.

```
function my_function(array $array) { ...
```

Then if you call it with something other than an array, you'll get a TypeError.

Unfortunately, there will still be a problem somewhere else in your code, where something you thought was an array is actually a string.

Setting up your function like this will generate an error earlier, *which is good*, because it will make it more obvious where the problem is. If you modify your function to ignore the problem instead, it will probably just create more confusing behavior and potentially different errors.